# How I can add separate project folder in my React App and keep it in secure auth

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am working on a React web application, with Google Firebase.
I have one other project done in simple HTML and JavaScript, which I want to secure with current React web app. When the user is login to the React app, he should see the link, and if user click on that link the HTML JavaScript app will render and display. If the token expire, the user will be redirect back to login page and he/she will not able to stay in that HTML JavaScript folder.

**Here is my navigation rout**

```
const Navigation = () => (
  <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
    {authUser =>
      authUser ? (
        <NavigationAuth authUser={authUser} />
      ) : (
          <NavigationNonAuth />
        )
    }
  </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
);

const NavigationAuth = ({ authUser }) => (
  <ul >
    <li>
      <NavLink to={ROUTES.HOME}>Home</NavLink>
    </li>
    <li>
      <NavLink to={ROUTES.ABOUT}>About</NavLink>
    </li>
    <li>
      <NavLink to={ROUTES.HTML_JS_Folder}>HTML project which I want to secure</NavLink>
    </li>
  </ul>
  );

const NavigationNonAuth = ({ authUser }) => (
  <ul >
    <li>
      <NavLink to={ROUTES.HOME}>Home</NavLink>
    </li>
    <li>
      <NavLink to={ROUTES.ABOUT}>About</NavLink>
    </li>
  </ul>
  );
```

I created the routes and as you can see the NavigationAuth contain the link to the simple folder containing index.html file which I want to render.